# Trouble deleting a node from Binary Search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble deleting a node from a binary search tree.

```
void BST::delete_node(Node* out)
{
   Node* tmp;
   Node* cur;
   if(out->get_left() == NULL || out->get_right() == NULL) {
        tmp = out;
   }
   else {
        tmp = get_succ(out);
   }

   if(tmp->get_left() != NULL) {
        cur = tmp->get_left();
   }
   else {
        cur = tmp->get_right();
   }

   if(cur != NULL) {
        cur->add_parent(tmp->get_parent());
   }

   if(tmp->get_parent() == NULL) {
           root = cur;
   }
   else if(tmp == (tmp->get_parent())->get_left()) {
        (tmp->get_parent())->add_left(cur);
   }

   else {
        (tmp->get_parent())->add_right(cur);
   }

   if(tmp->get_key() != out->get_key()) {
        out = nullptr;
   }
}
```

What seems to be the problem here, that is causing nodes to not be deleted from the binary search tree.

Comment: You have got to explain your algorithm in English.

Comment: As part of your explanation, a description of the roles played by each variable would be helpful. The names `out`, `tmp`, and `cur` fail to tell me anything useful about their roles.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you could pick a simple case to analyze? Step through your code and prove to us that it should successfully delete a node in that case. Draw some pictures if it helps.

Comment: A [mre] would include a function that defines a `BST` (with no user input needed), calls `delete_node()`, then produces some output to demonstrate that the node has not been deleted. *This might also help clarify the intended use of `delete_node()`, although explicitly writing out documentation would be better.*